# Running Java on Cloud 9

Tags: java, class, cloud9-ide

I really want to use Cloud 9 (http://c9.io) to run java and I try

```
javac file.java
```

then

```
java file.class
```

But I always get this

```
Error: Could not find or load main class
```

How can I fix this and is there an easier way to run the program and do you need the program (It's just a small test one)

(This is my first post, I tried looking for other answers and couldn't find anything, but if its in the wrong place sorry)

Comment: When using the java command don't write .class after file because it is already compiled.

Comment: Wow thank you do much, I did not expect an answer so soon, it works now sorry for wasting time on a stupid mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try `java file` instead of `java file.class`